# How to store values continuously without overwriting the previous one?

Tags: arrays, matlab

My project is "optical flow estimation for flame detection in videos" In that while extracting feature values, I can only retain the last intensity value of the frame.

Here is my code

```
function [Iy, Ix, It] = grad3D(imNew,bFineScale,bInitialize)
persistent siz gx gg imPrev; 
 if nargin>2 && bInitialize 
 [gx, gg]= makeFilters(); 
if bFineScale

   siz = size(imNew);
   imPrev= single(imNew);
else% if ~bFineScale
    siz = floor(size(imNew)/2);
    %initialize imPrev to half the size
    imPrev = imresizeNN(single(imNew),siz);
    end
end
 if ~bFineScale 
imNew = imresizeNN(conv2(single(imNew),gg,'same'),siz);
 else imNew = single(imNew);
```

end

```
 Ix = conv2(gg,gx,imNew + imPrev,'same'); 
 Iy = conv2(gx,gg,imNew + imPrev,'same'); 
 It = conv2(gg,gg,imNew - imPrev,'same'); %L3
```

**% finally, store away the current image for use on next frame
 imPrev = imNew; 
 testfeature = mean(imPrev);
 save testfeature testfeature**

```
[gx, gg]= makeFilters() x = (-1:1); 
gg = single(gaussgen(0.67,3));
gx = single(-x.*gg*3);
```

In the highlighted coding(`testfeature=mean(imprev)`). I can be able to get only the intensity value of last frame extracted...But i need the values for all the extracted frames. I need the value to be stored row wise in a matrix file.

Comment: What is the programming language?

Comment: @EternalHour Looks like Matlab.

Comment: I'm confused. Your testfeature seems to be the means of the columns of an image. Do you want something like `features = []; for i=1:10 feature = mean(image); features = [features; feature]; end`. This saves the "feature vectors" row-wise in a matrix, however it would be slow due to the lack of pre-allocation (there are solutions to this).

Comment: Yes, you are right.The test feature denotes the intensity column of an image.I will get an 1*256 value in a matrix,suppose if the total frames  extracted are 331..Then i need to get 331*256 (like 1*256,1*256) to be stored in a row.But while using the above code,i am getting only the intensity value of the last extracted frame...

Comment: Where do your images come from? Are you looping over a source matrix, from which you extract them? If so, this is the very place where you could and should save the feature data in the manner I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: i am extracting image frames from videos...for example if my video length is 10 sec,it produces around 331 frames...And i need intensity mean values of all the 331 frames to get stored in matrix one by one...The above code returns me only the last value stored in the matrix...

Comment: Your approach is problematic. It would be better to make `testfeature` a return value and construct the matrix in the calling function.